# Can I study angular2 in official website's example?

Tags: angular

I need to study angular2, there are not many documents about it, so I decide to study angualr2 in official website: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

and I installed angular2 boilerplate from https://github.com/buckyroberts/angular-2-template.

When I following the course, somethings are different.

**1**

the tutorial on official website they import angular core like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```

but the boilerplate:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

Is the tutorial on official site based on angular 1? not angular 2?

**2**

At the part of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html#!#two-way-binding .

The official tutorial import `angular/form`, and finally possible two-way binding.

but the boilerplate, they don't import `angular/form` but possible two-way binding.

Is it different?

I am so confused.

What is the best way to study angular2 ?  I think there are many versions also, any better idea?

Comment: That boilerplate uses [old beta version](https://github.com/buckyroberts/angular-2-template/blob/master/package.json) of angular, things have changed since then, mainly how/where angular modules are packaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**https://github.com/buckyroberts/angular-2-template** demonstrates **older version** example.

You can refer to new version content here : **https://github.com/angular/quickstart**

**FYI** : New version,

**1)**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

was there in **`beta version`**, but then Angular2 went through **`RC(release candidate)`** and **`final version`**. So it was removed and changed to **`@angular/core`** since **`RC`**

**2)** same way with **`angular/form`**, its now **`@angular/forms`**.

**For detail information please check this out : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md**

Comment: I need angular2. is it angular2? it seems like angular1... I should use ionic2 framework later so

Comment: I have provided new angualar2 version reference only.

Comment: so you mean angular2 is now stable, so the new version of angular is not use  "angular2" anymore, just say "@angular" right?

Comment: yes exactly its now `@angular/...`. Angular2 work is still in progress...But they have made `Angular2.0.0 stable`.